# Understanding class name prop as used here: <input type="text" class="{email: true}" />

Tags: css

browsing some html code I find a text input coded as:

```
<input type="text" name="Email<%=orderRow.ID %>_<%=i %>" class="{email: true}" />
```

but need help understanding what's happening with the class declaration. It's not part of hte .net-ness of the page, right - lack of '<%' and '%>' is telling me that. But I haven't seen an object used in a class name before.

thx

Comment: Me neither. What does this look like in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from jQuery Validation. It is a method used to set the required fields and properly formatted fields.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

To be more specific it is part of the metadata plugin for jQuery Validation.

Answer (score 2):

The object for the class name is using a jQuery validate plugin. Basically it tells the validate class to validate that input as an email address.

At least, that's what I've used it for. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look for some Javascript code verifying the form when it's posted. It looks like data that such a script could use.